# How to secure webapps on local domains

Tags: ssl

How do I ensure that a web app at`example.local` has the same level of protection as `example.com`, that is authenticity of the host and encryption of traffic?

How do I set this up in a Linux server and major browsers? I would prefer the same certificate in the browser to protect multiple domains.

Comment: Set up your own PKI, distribute the Root CA certificate to the clients

Answer (score 1):

You have several options.

As Mathias suggests above, you can create your own CA infrastructure and sign your own CSRs with your own CA key.  This has the advantage of being cheap/free, though it requires some technical clue.  It has the disadvantage that you need to install your CA root certificate as globally-trusted on all clients.  Moreover, many applications won't allow you to specify a root CA as being trusted only for certain parts of the DNS, so you have to be quite sure of your CA's security, or you'll fatally weaken the security of **all** SSL on those clients.

Or you can declare a subzone of your corporate DNS for internal use, say `int.example.com`, and run split-horizon DNS (so that internal clients can resolve eg `mail.int.example.com` while the rest of the world cannot).  Most big registrars will allow you to prove that you control `example.com` once, then will happily sign anything for a CN inside that zone, even if the CN in question doesn't appear in the global DNS.  The advantage of this is that the certificates you produce should be accepted by all clients without any additional work.  The disadvantage is that you have to pay for exach certificate issued, and since many bucket SSL shops aren't set up for this kind of work, you may have to pay the big bucks that the large registrars demand.

There are doubtless other options, that others may post as answers of their own.  As so often, it comes down to whether you want to spend time or money.  Pick one.